# Finding records which belong to multiple models with HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Track model has_and_belongs_to_many :moods, :genres, and :tempos (each of which likewise has_and_belongs_to_many :tracks).

I'm trying to build a search "filter" where users can specify any number of genres, moods, and tempos which will return tracks that match any conditions from each degree of filtering.

An example query might be

```
params[:genres] => "Rock, Pop, Punk"
params[:moods] => "Happy, Loud"
params[:tempos] => "Fast, Medium"
```

If I build an array of tracks matching all those genres, how can I select from that array those tracks which belong to any and all of the mood params, then select from that second array, all tracks which also match any and all of the tempo params?

I'm building the initial array with

```
@tracks = []
Genre.find_all_by_name(genres).each do |g|
  @tracks = @tracks | g.tracks
end
```

where `genres = params[:genres].split(",")`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working

```
@tracks = []
Genre.find_all_by_name(genres).each do |g|
  g.tracks.each do |t|
    temptempos = []
    tempartists = []
    tempmoods = []
    t.tempos.each do |m|
      temptempos.push(m.name)
    end
    tempartists.push(t.artist)
    t.moods.each do |m|
      tempmoods.push(m.name)
    end
    if !(temptempos & tempos).empty? && !(tempartists & artists).empty? && !(tempmoods & moods).empty?
      @tracks.push(t)
    end
  end
end
@tracks = @tracks.uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using your database to actually perform this query as that would be a lot more efficient.

You can try to join all these tables in SQL first and then using conditional queries i.e. where clauses to first try it out.

Once you succeed you can write it in the Active Record based way. I think its fairly important that you write it in SQL first so that you can properly understand whats going on.